# Copy elements from List<byte> to another List<byte> doing a deep copy

Tags: c#, deep-copy

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.7.

I have two `List<byte>` and I want to copy all the elements in one of them to the another one.

I want to reuse the list, so I don't want to create a new one when I have to copy the contents of one list to the other.

```
List<byte> list1 = new List<byte>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<byte> list2 = new List<byte>() { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
```

If I want to copy the content of `list2` into `list1`, what do I have to do if I want to replace the content of `list1` with the content of `list2`?

I want to copy the values, not to copy a reference to the values in `list2`. If I modify a value in `list2` I don't want that modification in `list1`.

I haven't found any method that does a deep copy in `List<T>`. The only I think I can use is [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7) but I haven't found any reference about if this method does a deep or swallow copy.

What do I have to do if I want to replace the content of `list1` with the content of `list2` doing a deep copy?

Comment: Deep/shallow doesn't really apply to value types. If a type isn't a reference type and  doesn't contain any references, then copying it will copy everything that it contains.

Comment: Simple value types (`byte`, `int`) are stored in-place in the `List`s, not as references.

Comment: Just to be clear, `.AddRange` does in fact do a shallow copy, but as others have stated, this fact is meaningless when what you're copying is primitive value-types, you're copying the value, not a reference to it, anyway. Copying value-types that contain references will be troublesome, however. You will get a copy of the value-type part, but that copy will contain a copy of the reference as well, and the object it refers to will thus not be duplicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`byte` is a *value-type*. So if you copy them, they are independent from the orignial value. Here are no references involved. And the term "deep-copy" doesn't make any sense if the lists contain only `byte` values.

So yes, to copy the elements of `list2` into `list1` you can simply do

```
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

You might want to `list1.Clear()` before if you don't want to keep the previous content.